# Should threading be preferred in CPU intensive tasks or IO intensive tasks?

Tags: operating-system

Should threading be preferred in CPU intensive tasks or IO intensive tasks?

In my opinion it should be "IO intensive tasks" because of CPU Intensive tasks the CPU is already involved to the maximum work.

Comment: Related? http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/179488/why-is-multithreading-often-preferred-for-improving-performance

Comment: If you are using kernel threads, you could do it in a CPU intensive task on a multiprocessor system.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a multi core processor and the task can be split into separate parts, you gain significant processing power on CPU intensive tasks.

Mark